# How to select top 5 usernames with highest score

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `username` and `score`. Both are connected using `user_id`.

I want to select the top 5 usernames who have the highest score. I am trying following query but it is not working:

```
SELECT `user_name`  
  FROM `username` 
 WHERE `user_id` = ( SELECT `u_id` 
                       FROM `score` 
                       ORDER BY `high_score` DESC 
                       LIMIT 5 )
```

I get this error when I run the above query: `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: You would use a [MySQL join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to achieve this. And you can't do `=` towards multiple values, ergo the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `WHERE` clause your are trying to assert the congruence or equality of one value (on the left side) to a list of values (on the right side).

Use the `IN` operator to achieve this because it will compare the left value with any of the right values.

The following is your corrected code.

```
SELECT    `user_name`
    FROM  `username`
    WHERE `user_id` IN(
              SELECT        `u_id`
                  FROM      `score`
                  ORDER BY  `high_score` DESC
                  LIMIT 5
              );
```

As a manner of style using a join is clearer and more elegant especially for a simple query like this.

```
SELECT        `u`.`user_name`
    FROM      `username` AS `u`
    INNER JOIN `score` AS `s`
        ON     `u`.`user_id` = `s`.`u_id`
    ORDER BY  `s`.`high_score` DESC
    LIMIT      5;
```

Comment: I am getting error that IN is not supported my Server version for mysql is 5.0.92

Comment: Re-read that error. No error will tell you that "a future version might be allowing this as an operator but I'm not" simply because it can't know what future operators will be implemented.

Comment: The error is a very generic error that tells you "go read the manual for your server version" which is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) and it says that the IN operator is supported by MySQL 5.0.

Comment: to add to a perfect answer you can even use SELECT TOP 5 instead of using LIMIT 5.

Comment: `SELECT TOP` is MSSQL/MSAccess specific, it doesn't work in MySQL and since the question is tagged MySQL...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT `user_name`  
FROM `username`,`score` 
WHERE `user_id` = `u_id` 
ORDER BY `high_score` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```